# Unable to load .pkl file

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, pickle

I am new to python and so to pickle files. I have been doing course on Machine Learning on Udacity when i came across this problem. This is my code:

```
import pickle 
enron_data = pickle.load(open(filename, "r"))
```

Through lesson 5 we had to load Enron Dataset from a .pkl file in python, but i am continuously getting following error:

```
as@LENOVO:~/Desktop/ud120-projects$ python datasets_questions/explore_enron_data.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datasets_questions/explore_enron_data.py", line 20, in <module>
    enron_data = pickle.load(open("/home/as/Desktop/ud120-projects/final_project/final_project_dataset.pkl", "r"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 966, in load_string
    raise ValueError, "insecure string pickle"
```